# Javascript - Adding additional card/points to hand if less than 17

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add an if statement that will add another card to the dealerHand if it is less than 17.

Currently, it is just logging:

```
7
19
[ { suit: '♦', value: 9, points: 9 },
{ suit: '♠', value: 'K', points: 10 },
{ suit: '♥', value: 5, points: 5 } ]
```

It is adding the 3rd object no matter what and the points are not being added to the total (19).

```
let playerPoints = 0,
    dealerPoints = 0;

for (let { points } of playerHand) {
    playerPoints += points;
}

for (let { points } of dealerHand) {
    dealerPoints += points
}
    // console.log(playerPoints);
    console.log(dealerPoints);


let = totalPoints;

if (dealerPoints < 17) {

 dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
 totalPoints += points
} else {
 return
}
  console.log(dealerHand);
```

Right now, we've addressed the if statement to only add a
card if the total value of the 2 cards is less than 17,
but I need for that 3rd card's points to be added to the first 
two card's points.

```
9
[ { suit: '♦', value: 3, points: 3 },
{ suit: '♥', value: 6, points: 6 },
{ suit: '♠', value: 'A', points: 11 } ]
```

First two cards add up to 9, the 3rd card should make it 20.

*EDIT*

```
let totalPoints;

if (dealerPoints < 17) {
  dealerHand.push(dealRandomCard());
  totalPoints += points
} else {
  return
}

let totalDealerHand = 0;

for (let card of dealerHand) {
 totalDealerHand += card.points;
}
 totalDealerHand = dealerHand.reduce(( total , amount ) => total + 
 amount);
 // console.log(playerHand);
 console.log(totalDealerHand);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if (dealerPoints += points < 17)
```

You can't use the *+=* operator like so. I guess what you want to test is

```
if (dealerPoints < 17)
```

Comment: good catch, that worked, but now i'm trying to add the point value to the other 2 cards if the total is less than 17.

Comment: I will need you to break it down for me, what do you mean by *add the point value to the other 2 cards* ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the cards to get the total:

```
let totalDealerHand = 0;
for (let card of dealerHand) {
  totalDealerHand+= card.points;
}
// totalDealerHand now equals the total number of the cards
```

Using the [Array.reduce() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
let totalDealerHand = dealerHand.reduce((a,b)=>a+b);
```

Comment: ah that makes sense. when i log it though, it's just returning [object Object][object Object][object Object]

Comment: sorry had work to do :p. My mistake, their was an error within my code: `let totalDealerHand = dealerHand.reduce((a,b)=>a.points+b.points);`

Comment: np, but it's giving me NaN now